# VueJS - mouse event doesn't work if element is placed inside Vue app div

Tags: html, vue.js, mouseevent, vuejs2, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In my application, I'd like to use *bootstrap-datetimepicker* library, which lets you have a date and time picker on the website.

I just put the datepicker in my HTML (some divs and input).
I also added the script that initializes the whole thing.

I observed a strange behaviour: if my datetimepicker is placed inside Vue div, it doesn't work! (when I click on the input field, the calendar should be displayed).
When I put the picker outside of Vue DIV it works perfectly.

Generally, I noticed that Vue blocks mouse events, i had the same issue with MetricsGraphics.js library (for drawing graphs) - if i put it inside Vue DIV, mouse hover events do not work at all. i had to put it outside of Vue.

What's the reason for that? In case of datetimepicker, I can't put it outside of Vue, because I'd like to use Vue capabilities on it.

I didn't include any code, but basically, this doesn't work:

```
<div>
    <div id="vue-app">
        <!-- DATE_TIME PICKER: -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And this works:

```
<div>
    <div id="vue-app">

    <div>

    <!-- DATE_TIME PICKER: -->           
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();` executes, `#datetimepicker1` does not exist because vue hasn't finished parsing the template.

The correct way to initialize your datetimepicker within vue is to do it inside `mounted` lifecycle hook. Also, to make it sound more *vue-ish*, you could use a `ref` to your DOM element instead of an `id`. Check out the example below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  mounted() {
    let dt = this.$refs['datetimepicker1']
    $(dt).datetimepicker()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div id="vue-app">
        <!-- DATE_TIME PICKER: -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' ref='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
<div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Calendar now shows each time. Now my only issue is the fact that @change and v-model do not work on datetimepicker input. I'm trying to figure it out now. Bound v-model variable stays null.

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should post your new issue in a new question.

Comment: It seems that datetimepicker uses jQuery events, not native ones. So I have to update vue data manually on each change, i can't use v-model

Comment: Yes.. there's also a vue component that wraps datetimepicker. http://haixing-hu.github.io/vue-datetime-picker/

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Unfortunately it requires you to use node.JS, which I have no idea about